# Compiling C++ using PHP

Tags: php, c++, linux, gcc, g++

I'm trying to develop an online judge using PHP to be hosted on linux

I wrote the code below in test.php file

```
<?php
    exec("sudo chown `rofaelemil` /var/www", $output, $returnVal);
    exec("g++ /var/www/qwerty.cpp -o /var/www/binary", $output, $returnVal);
    echo $output;
    exec("cat /var/www/qwe.txt | /var/www/binary", $output, $returnVal);
    echo $output;
    exec("gcc /var/www/qwerty.c -o /var/www/binary", $output, $returnVal);
    echo $output;
    exec("cat /var/www/qwe.txt | /var/www/binary", $output, $returnVal);
    echo $output;
?>
```

The output was

```
ArrayArrayArrayArray
```

Could anyone configure the problem

Comment: try `print_r($output)` instead of `echo`

Comment: have you tried `print_r` instead of `echo`?

Comment: Replace `echo` with `var_dump($output)`. *Edit:* Wow, I lost by a couple of seconds :)

Comment: Add `2>&1` to capture stderr as well.

Comment: `sudo` is often configured by default _not_ to work in situations like this. It requires an actual TTY, and that can be changed in the sudoers file by removing the `Defaults requiretty` directive.

Comment: On a side note: be extremely careful allowing remote code execution like this.

Answer (score 4):

`$output` contains the output of the program you `exec`ed, line by line, you can't echo an array, `print_r` it.

Next time please consult the documentation of php, you could have gotten this information there. See [exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php).